# How do multifilter in dataGridView with two textboxes?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015

For example when the same First Name with different Last Name
to filter name and write in Last Name filter, but keeping the names filter.

Example whith a textbox:

Connection:

```
public void read_data(string query, ref DataSet principal, string tabla)
{
    try
    {
       string cadena = "Server=0.0.0.0; Database=DB; Uid=user; Pwd=pass";
       MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(cadena);
       MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
       cn.Open();
       MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       da.Fill(principal, tabla);
       cn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Load dataGridView:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.read_data("Select * From reg", ref result, "reg");
    this.filtro = ((DataTable)result.Tables["regi"]).DefaultView;
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = filtro;
}
```

Event:

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string data_output = " ";
    string[] search_word = this.textBox1.Text.Split(' ');

    foreach (string word in search_word)
    {
        if (data_output.Length == 0)
        {
            data_output = "(FirstName LIKE '%" + word + "%')";
        }
        else
        {
            data_output += "(FirstName LIKE '%" + word + "%')";
        }
    }
    this.filtro.RowFilter = data_output;
}
```

Comment: Does your example provided works? i.e. Does it filter records when you specify multiple Firstnames separated by space?

Comment: No, I doesn't.  Only a name

Comment: Anyway, check the answer I just provided to see if it helps you to achieve your objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to achieve your requirement.

Create a common function to call from both the text boxes as below

```
    private string GetFilterExpression(string sFilterExprValue, string sFilterFieldName)
    {
        string sFilterExpr = "";
        string[] search_word = sFilterExprValue.Split(' ');

        foreach (string word in search_word)
        {
            if (sFilterExpr.Length == 0)
            {
                sFilterExpr = "(" + sFilterFieldName + " LIKE '%" + word + "%')";
            }
            else
            {
                sFilterExpr += " AND (" + sFilterFieldName + " LIKE '%" + word + "%')";
            }
        }

        return sFilterExpr;
    }
```

Call the common function from key up event of both the text boxes as shown below;

Text Box 1 with First Name filter

```
    private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Text box to enter Firstname filter
        string sFilter = GetFilterExpression(this.textBox1.text, "FirstName");

        if (!this.textBox2.text)
        {
            string sLastNameFilter = GetFilterExpression(this.textBox2.text, "LastName");

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sLastNameFilter))     // Concat the Last Name Filter 
                sFilter +=  String.IsNullOrEmpty(sFilter) ? "" : " AND " + sLastNameFilter;
        }

        this.filtro.RowFilter = sFilter;
    }
```

Text Box 2 with Last Name filter

```
    private void textBox2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Text box to enter Lastname filter
        // Assume the field storing last name is 'Lastname'
        string sFilter = GetFilterExpression(this.textBox2.text, "LastName");

        if (!this.textBox1.text)
        {
            string sFirstNameFilter = GetFilterExpression(this.textBox1.text, "FirstName");

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sFirstNameFilter))
                sFilter += String.IsNullOrEmpty(sFilter) ? "" : " AND " + sFirstNameFilter;
        }

        this.filtro.RowFilter = sFilter;
    }
```

Hope this helps and mark it as so if this addresses your issue.

*Edited*: to update the textBox2_Keyup event to concatenate any filter expression typed into textBox1

Comment: When I type in textbox1 if you filter, but writing in the textbox2 loops through all the records again without maintain the previous filter.

Comment: As per your comment I presume you used the suggested code fragment as it is. And in the code there was typo in the `textbox2_keyup` event and that would have overridden the `textbox1` filter. Check the edited answer.

Comment: It works now, but I made some changes my program, I did  a dynamic filtering with three textboxes.
I used your code you provided me in other program, thanks

Comment: Glad that the code was useful and you managed to enhance as needed.